# Error for RenderedWith property while using GetPublishInfo for Component Template

Tags: 2011, templating

It looks like I come across a bug on Tridion API's, while working on DotNet Templating using Tridion 2011 SP1.

```
ICollection<PublishInfo> publishInfos = PublishEngine.GetPublishInfo(mIdentifiableObject);
```

While executing `GetPublishInfo` for Component Template, method returns `ICollection` of `PublishInfo` Objects.

Here `PublishInfo` has properties like

- Publicaton
- PublicationTarget
- PublishedAt
- PublishedBy
- RenderedWith

Here, `RenderedWith` returns of type `Template`.

When we execute `GetPublishInfo` for `Component Template`, `RenderedWith` property will have `Component` as value (which is correct).

But unfortunately, `RenderedWith` supports only of type `Template`.

Due to this, we get error as

> **Unable to cast object of type 'Tridion.ContentManager.ContentManagement.Component' to type 'Tridion.ContentManager.CommunicationManagement.Template'**

Now my question is,

> **Is anyone come across with this problem. If so, how you fixed?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two ways to fix the problem,

1. Raise a support ticket, which might take some turnaround time for getting the solution

   - However, `RenderedWith` should return of type `VersionedItem` rather than `Template`
2. Have a workaround fix on the template for time-being

### Workaround fix:

```
private static readonly PropertyInfo mCurrentStateProperty = typeof(PublishInfo).GetProperty("CurrentState", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

ICollection<PublishInfo> publishInfos = PublishEngine.GetPublishInfo(mIdentifiableObject);

IEnumerable<IdentifiableObject> identifiableObjectList = publishInfos.Select((i) =>
    {
        PublishInfoData publishInfoData = mCurrentStateProperty.GetValue(i, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic, null, null, null) as PublishInfoData;

        if (publishInfoData != null)
            return GetObject(publishInfoData.RenderedWith.IdRef);

        return null;
    });
```

Finally, Customer Support has provided a hotfix (`CM_2011.1.2.87741`) on top of `Tridion 2011 SP1-HR2`

**[Hotfix 'CM_2011.1.2.87741'](https://www.sdltridionworld.com/downloads/hotfixes/SDL_Tridion_2011_SP1_2/index.aspx)**

With the hotfix, a new property (**"RenderedItem"**) has been introduced. `RenderedItem` is of type `IdentifiableObject`

Comment: Even if you implement the work around, I'd appreciate if you report it via customer support so that we can fix it - maybe it has already been fixed in newer versions, can't check it now.

Comment: @NunoLinhares: Yeah, I already informed my support team to raise the support ticket.